# Difference between se fâcher, s'énerver and s'embêter

Tags: vocabulaire

Quelle est la différence entre se fâcher, s'énerver et s'embêter ?

Est-ce que tous les trois sont utilisés dans le langage courant ?

Comment: Que donne une recherche dans un dictionnaire?

Comment: @Toto le dictionnaire donne pour chaque mot plusieurs possibilités mais pour tous les trois on peut trouver ärgern, aufregen (to get angry, to get upset). Je voudrait savoir s'il y a une différence entre les trois, qui n'est pas indiquée dans le dictionnaire, car je veux les différencier si je les écris dans mon cahier de vocabulaire :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se fâcher: 1/ to get angry. 2/ to fall out after a row. 
“Le prof s’est fâché quand il a trouvé du yaourt étalé sur son bureau” : (he got really cross, he got mad). 
“Pierre et son frêre se sont fâchés à mort”  : Pierre and his brother have completely fallen out.

But Watch out:

Je suis en colère contre mon cousin: I’m mad at my cousin
Je suis fâchée avec ma tante: I fell out with my aunt.

S’énerver: to get cranky or agitated. ”T’énerve pas, Michel, pense à ta tension”! (Don’t get stressed out, Michel, think of your blood pressure).

S’embêter: in a reflexive form: to be bored. “Elle s’embête comme un rat mort” (she’s bored to death)

In a non reflexive form, it’s to pester, annoy, to be nuisance: “Arrête de m’embêter! Stop pestering/hassling me.

Another nice word for that is “enquiquiner”. “Qu’est ce qu’il peut être enquiquinant, ce gars-là” (so tedious, annoying)(and generally boring too!)

All three verbs are very commonly used, yes.